# Meteor; How do I make this work, iron route + templates issue

Tags: javascript, meteor

Basically I have a bootstrap navbar with a login button that uses steam API. I'm returned with

```
C:\Users\Farhan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.4_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:280
                        throw(ex);
                              ^ ReferenceError: Template is not defined
    at meteorInstall.lib.main.js (lib/main.js:1:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
    at C:\Users\Farhan\csgofiyav1\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\app\app.js:68:1
    at C:\Users\Farhan\csgofiyav1\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:297:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Farhan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.4_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at C:\Users\Farhan\csgofiyav1\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:133:5 Exited with code: 8 Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

as my error. My codes are:

in layoutDefault.html

```
<template name="layoutDefault">
    ..
                        <a class="steamLogin" href="#">Login With Steam</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    {{> yield}}
    </template>
```

and in main.js

```
Template.layoutDefault.events({
    'click .steamLogin': function(event){
        Meteor.loginWithSteam();
    }
});
```

routes.js

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layoutDefault'
});

Router.route('/', {
    template: 'main'
});

Router.route('/contact', {
    template: 'contact'
});
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If the main.js is under /imports, you need to import it (it won't be lazy-loaded)... That might be the reason why Template is not defined. Add: import { Template } from 'meteor/templating'

Comment: thanks for that, updated question

Answer (score 0):

Error no longer exists, but, now says

```
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "./layoutDefault.html" in /C/Users/Farhan/csgofiyav1/client/main.js
(web.browser)
```

shfited main.js to client folder

*client/main.js*

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './templates/layout/layoutDefault.html';

Template.layoutDefault.events({
    'click .steamLogin': function(event){
        Meteor.loginWithSteam();
    }
});
```

*client/templates/layout/layoutDefault.html*

```
<template name="layoutDefault">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        .....
                    <li>
                        <a class="steamLogin" href="#">Login With Steam</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    {{> yield}}
    </template>
```

Comment: You don't have to import HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it's working now. I had to update server side main.js

Added this

```
    if(Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
      { service: 'steam' },
      {
        $set: {
          loginStyle: 'redirect',
          timeout: 10000 // 10 seconds
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Then instead of having an event for the template, I routed the link to a login.html where in the client side js, once that template is rendered, I would run Meteor.loginWithSteam();

```
Template.login.rendered = function() {
    if(!this._rendered) {
      this._rendered = true;
      Meteor.loginWithSteam();
    }
}
```